# if i have many locks updating a hash map, what lock do i need to get an up to date value of the map

Tags: java, concurrency

i have a map defined as below:

```
private Map<String, TreeSet<String>> companyOrderMap = new HashMap <String, TreeSet<String>>();
```

I have thread 1 inserting into map

```
lockA.lock()
companyOrderMap.put(key, bids);
lockA.unlock()
```

Also thread 2:

```
lockB.lock()
companyOrderMap.put(key, bids);
lockB.unlock()
```

in concurrency in practice it says visibility id guaranteed if everything is being done by the same lock, but i have two different locks editing the map? how can i get full visibility?

Will this work?

```
synchronized(companyOrderMap) {
        //print all contents
    }
```

Comment: You get correct visibility by using the same lock.

Comment: This code isn't threadsafe, because thread 1 and thread 2 don't lock each other out of modifying the HashMap, so they can both be modifying it at the same time. HashMap is not designed to be used concurrently. Either use just one lock, or use a concurrent Map implementation such as ConcurrentHashMap: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html

Comment: *Why* do you have two locks? Your question is founded on a basic error.

Comment: for performance reasons

Comment: @user3809938 performance means nothing if the code is not correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using multiple locks is incorrect.

Locks (and synchronized blocks) establish a happens-before relationship: the unlock of a lock happens before the locking of the same lock; this means that the updates that happen whilst holding the lock are visible to the next thread to acquire the lock.

If you use separate locks, there is no such happens-before, so the "second" access doesn't have visibility of the updates effected by the "first" access; or, worse, the two accesses happen at the same time, and corrupt the internal state of the hash map.

Instead, you have to use just one lock for all accesses to the map (and the same lock for both reads and writes), to ensure that they happen serially, and with full visibility.

You might probably be better off using a `ConcurrentHashMap`, which is designed for concurrent access.

Comment: will ConcurrentHashMap prevent modification of the same object at sometime?

Comment: OP also needs a concurrent set and probably `computeIfAbsent`.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- not necessarily; that depends on whether the set is then updated once in the map. If not, the HB created by the lock ensures the visibility of the set's contents.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- (one might wish to mitigate the risk of unintentional modification by putting `unmodifiableSet(new TreeSet<>(bids))`)

Comment: @AndyTurner Fair. I suppose I'm being overly defensive given the existing code.

Comment: @chrylis-onstrike- also fair :)

Comment: I do suggest including `computeIfAbsent`, as otherwise we're likely to see a hand-rolled test-and-set routine for adding new sets.

Comment: The two accesses don’t need to happen at the same time to corrupt the internal state of the hash map. The timing is entirely irrelevant.